# How to style the "selected" item for a DropDownButtonFormField?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The selected item of my DropDownButtonFormField is different than the ones in the item list.

Here is what I am trying to do

```
class CurrencyDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  const CurrencyDropDown({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CurrencyDropDownState createState() => _CurrencyDropDownState();
}

class _CurrencyDropDownState extends State<CurrencyDropDown> {
  String selected = "EUR";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
      value: selected,
      hint: new Text("Select your currency...", textAlign: TextAlign.center),
      items: ["USD", "EUR", "CHF"]
          .map((label) => DropdownMenuItem(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset(
                      'icons/currency/${label.toLowerCase()}.png',
                      package: 'currency_icons',
                      width: 30,
                    ),
                    Text(label),
                  ],
                ),
                value: label,
              ))
          .toList(),
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() => selected = value);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and displaying the widget like this

```
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
              width: 200,
              child: CurrencyDropDown(),
            ),
```

And here is how it looks when selecting
[image]

and displaying the selection.
[image]

I would like the selected value to have the same display like in the dropdown list, with nice spacing and alignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your selected item is different to your dropdown is because your row width is condensed in your selected field. You can fix it by adding in your `DropdownButtonFormField`

```
isExpanded: true,
```